# How to refer to connections set through environment variables?

Tags: airflow

I set my database connection via an environment variable like so:

```
AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_MSSQL=mssql+pyodbc://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>
```

Should this connection be visible in UI with **Conn Id** = `my_mssql`?

How do I reference a connection set up through an environment variable?

The reason I am asking is that the code below throws an exception stating that the connection with id `my_mssql` is not present:

```
ms_hook = MsSqlHook(mssql_conn_id='my_mssql')
ms_connection = ms_hook.get_conn()
```

> airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The conn_id `my_mssql` isn't
>   defined

Comment: Just as a double check, even if it may be infeasible "programatically", but have you tried to set up the connection through the UI and check if that works? This may better pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Hello, did you finally make it?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow connections created using Environment Variables won't appear in the UI.

It feels that your DAG does not have that environment variable if it is throwing error.

Can you double-check using:

```py
import os
print(os.environ)
```